# Combining Rolling Origin Forecast Resampling and Group V-Fold Cross-Validation in rsample

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, r-caret

I would like to use the R package `rsample` to generate resamples of my data.

The package offers the function `rolling_origin` to produce resamples that keep the time series structure of the data. This means that training data (in the package called `analysis`) are always in the past of test data (`assessment`).

On the other hand I would like to perform block samples of the data. This means that groups of rows are kept together during sampling. This can be done using the function `group_vfold_cv`. As groups one could think of are months. Say, we want to do time series cross validation always keeping months together.

Is there a way to combine the two approaches in `rsample`?

I give examples for each procedure on its own:

```
## generate some data
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rsample)
my_dates = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), as.Date("2018/8/20"), "days")
some_data = data_frame(dates = my_dates) 
some_data$values = runif(length(my_dates))
some_data = some_data %>% mutate(month = as.factor(month(dates)))
```

This gives data of the following form

```
 A tibble: 232 x 3
   dates      values month 
   <date>      <dbl> <fctr>
 1 2018-01-01 0.235  1     
 2 2018-01-02 0.363  1     
 3 2018-01-03 0.146  1     
 4 2018-01-04 0.668  1     
 5 2018-01-05 0.0995 1     
 6 2018-01-06 0.163  1     
 7 2018-01-07 0.0265 1     
 8 2018-01-08 0.273  1     
 9 2018-01-09 0.886  1     
10 2018-01-10 0.239  1
```

Then we can e.g. produce samples that take 20 weeks of data and test on future 5 weeks (the parameter `skip` skips some rows extra):

```
rolling_origin_resamples <- rolling_origin(
  some_data,
  initial    = 7*20,
  assess     = 7*5,
  cumulative = TRUE,
  skip       = 7
)
```

We can check the data with the following code and see no overlap:

```
rolling_origin_resamples$splits[[1]] %>% analysis %>% tail
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  dates       values month 
  <date>       <dbl> <fctr>
1 2018-05-15 0.678   5     
2 2018-05-16 0.00112 5     
3 2018-05-17 0.339   5     
4 2018-05-18 0.0864  5     
5 2018-05-19 0.918   5     
6 2018-05-20 0.317   5 

### test data of first split:
rolling_origin_resamples$splits[[1]] %>% assessment
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  dates      values month 
  <date>      <dbl> <fctr>
1 2018-05-21  0.912 5     
2 2018-05-22  0.403 5     
3 2018-05-23  0.366 5     
4 2018-05-24  0.159 5     
5 2018-05-25  0.223 5     
6 2018-05-26  0.375 5
```

Alternatively we can split by months:

```
## sampling by month:
gcv_resamples = group_vfold_cv(some_data, group = "month", v = 5)
gcv_resamples$splits[[1]]  %>% analysis %>% select(month) %>% summary
gcv_resamples$splits[[1]] %>% assessment %>% select(month) %>% summary
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of the solution from @missuse, the way to achieve this is documented in the github issue: https://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/issues/42

Essentially, the idea is to first nest over your "blocks" and then `rolling_origin()` will allow you to roll over them, keeping complete blocks intact.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(rsample)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

# same data generation as before
my_dates = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), as.Date("2018/8/20"), "days")
some_data = data_frame(dates = my_dates)
some_data$values = runif(length(my_dates))
some_data = some_data %>% mutate(month = as.factor(month(dates)))

# nest by month, then resample
rset <- some_data %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  nest() %>%
  rolling_origin(initial = 1)

# doesn't show which month is which :(
rset
#> # Rolling origin forecast resampling 
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   splits       id    
#>   <list>       <chr> 
#> 1 <S3: rsplit> Slice1
#> 2 <S3: rsplit> Slice2
#> 3 <S3: rsplit> Slice3
#> 4 <S3: rsplit> Slice4
#> 5 <S3: rsplit> Slice5
#> 6 <S3: rsplit> Slice6
#> 7 <S3: rsplit> Slice7


# only January (31 days)
analysis(rset$splits[[1]])$data
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 31 x 2
#>    dates      values
#>    <date>      <dbl>
#>  1 2018-01-01 0.373 
#>  2 2018-01-02 0.0389
#>  3 2018-01-03 0.260 
#>  4 2018-01-04 0.803 
#>  5 2018-01-05 0.595 
#>  6 2018-01-06 0.875 
#>  7 2018-01-07 0.273 
#>  8 2018-01-08 0.180 
#>  9 2018-01-09 0.662 
#> 10 2018-01-10 0.849 
#> # ... with 21 more rows


# only February (28 days)
assessment(rset$splits[[1]])$data
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 28 x 2
#>    dates      values
#>    <date>      <dbl>
#>  1 2018-02-01 0.402 
#>  2 2018-02-02 0.556 
#>  3 2018-02-03 0.764 
#>  4 2018-02-04 0.134 
#>  5 2018-02-05 0.0333
#>  6 2018-02-06 0.907 
#>  7 2018-02-07 0.814 
#>  8 2018-02-08 0.0973
#>  9 2018-02-09 0.353 
#> 10 2018-02-10 0.407 
#> # ... with 18 more rows
```

Created on 2018-08-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 5):

This can also be accomplished with `tidyroll`, which is a small R package with a collection of convenience functions for working with time-series data with irregular time slices.

`rolling_origin_nested` is a wrapper around `rolling_origin` and has a number of nice features including allowing the user to select the unit (minute, day, week, month, etc.) over which to roll, a start and end date/time, and whether or not to temporarily extend the data so that all observations between `start` and `end` are predicted `assess` number of times.

```r
# devtools::install_github("gacolitti/tidyroll")

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rsample)
library(tidyroll)

my_dates = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), as.Date("2018/8/20"), "days")
some_data = data.frame(dates = my_dates) 
some_data$values = runif(length(my_dates))

roll <- rolling_origin_nested(some_data,
                              time_var = "dates",
                              unit = "month",
                              start = "2018-01-01")
roll
#> # Rolling origin forecast resampling 
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   splits        id    
#>   <list>        <chr> 
#> 1 <split [1/1]> Slice1
#> 2 <split [2/1]> Slice2
#> 3 <split [3/1]> Slice3
#> 4 <split [4/1]> Slice4
#> 5 <split [5/1]> Slice5
#> 6 <split [6/1]> Slice6
#> 7 <split [7/1]> Slice7

analysis(roll$splits[[1]])$data[[1]] %>% tail
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   dates               values
#>   <dttm>               <dbl>
#> 1 2018-01-26 00:00:00 0.0929
#> 2 2018-01-27 00:00:00 0.536 
#> 3 2018-01-28 00:00:00 0.194 
#> 4 2018-01-29 00:00:00 0.600 
#> 5 2018-01-30 00:00:00 0.449 
#> 6 2018-01-31 00:00:00 0.754

assessment(roll$splits[[1]])$data[[1]] %>% head
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   dates               values
#>   <dttm>               <dbl>
#> 1 2018-02-01 00:00:00  0.945
#> 2 2018-02-02 00:00:00  0.733
#> 3 2018-02-03 00:00:00  0.626
#> 4 2018-02-04 00:00:00  0.585
#> 5 2018-02-05 00:00:00  0.303
#> 6 2018-02-06 00:00:00  0.767
```

There are a couple of other convenience functions such as `fit_rsample_nested` and `predict_rsample_nested` that facilitate working with objects created with `rolling_origin_nested` and data preprocessing with `recipes`.

One really cool feature of `predict_rsample_nested` is the ability to pass additional `recipe` steps to impute predictor values that might not be available depending on the prediction date.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you would like to create resamples where you train on all data up to a certain month and evaluate on that month for every month.
I am not a `rsample` user but this can be achieved quite easy with base R. Here is one approach:

split data into a list by month

```
df <- split(some_data, some_data$month)
```

lapply along list elements defining train and test sets

```
df <- lapply(seq_along(df)[-length(df)], function(x){
  train <- do.call(rbind, df[1:x])
  test <- df[x+1]
  return(list(train = train,
              test = test))

})
```

the result df is a list of 7 elements each containing a train and test data frames.

Comment: thank you for coming back to me on this. In fact I would like to use rsample as it has the object set-up that the rest of my code is already built on. I also asked at rstudio and Max Kuhn, the author of the package works there. maybe he will help too. Thank you!

Comment: @Richard the code is quite easily changed to acquire train and test indexes which can be used with `caret`. I can show that if needed. I will also look into `rsample` package and if I get something working I will update the answer.

Comment: for rsample This would be great. For caret I don't need it at the moment. Unfortunately the built in models for keras do not contain all parameters that I want to tune (especially I am not sure about more than one hidden layer). So I thought about doing it outside using rsample and tfruns.

Comment: I wanted to get back to you on this even though I hadn't luck providing the requested solution. I checked `rsample` and I do not see a way to do stratified time series cross validation using this package. If it is really absent from the package I trust topepo would be willing to incorporate this functionality if you ask him nicely. EDIT: In fact this seems to be it: https://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/issues/42. Looks like it will be inbuilt when it is finished,

Comment: Thanks, I will link this question to their example.